# Rails6: Post deployment application shows SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, capistrano

The application was working perfectly fine till the latest deployment which started showing error in Developers Tools and on every tab that I try to click in the application.

Deployment is done trough `Capistrano`

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at application-00b7157c7.js:44883:1)
(index):261 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):261:1
(anonymous) @ (index):261
(index):268 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):268:5
(anonymous) @ (index):268
(index):285 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):285:5
```

This is where the error is thrown ->

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Javascript Version ->

```
Ext.getVersion('extjs');
constructor {shortVersion: '421883', version: '4.2.1.883'
```

JQuery is a part of application.js

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require js/bootstrap.min
//= require js/ekko-lightbox.min
//= require jquery.placeholder
//= require jquery-ui
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Do you have `jquery` imported in your html ? The error `$ is not defined` seems like pointing that javascript did not find `jquery`.

Comment: Did you try to install JS dependencies and compile them?

Comment: Hi, jQuery is a part of application.js and it has always been there. No changes at all but only some minor code changes

Answer (score 1):

My Gemfile was at -> jquery-rails (4.4.0) which got upgraded to  jquery-rails (4.5.0)during deployment.
I changed my Gemfile to restrict the jQuery version gem 'jquery-rails', '4.4.0' which fixed this problem